# Easier way of using Joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

Author:

> id    username    email   password    salt
>     email_salt  email_verified
>     ip_address

Author_threads:

> thread_id, author_id

Thread:

> id, title, content, created

Tag:

> id, name

Thread_tags:

> tad_id, thread_id

I want to select the latest 30 threads, their author and all their tags. This is the SQL statement I use:

```
       SELECT thread.title, thread.id as thread_id,
       thread.content, author.username, author.id as author_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.name ORDER BY tag.name DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags
       FROM thread 
       JOIN thread_tags ON thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
       JOIN tag ON thread_tags.tag_id = tag.id

       JOIN author_threads ON thread.id = author_threads.thread_id
       JOIN author ON author_threads.author_id = author.id

       GROUP BY thread.id DESC
       LIMIT 0, 30
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Is this MySQL? You should include the database type tag.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the GROUP BY should be ORDER BY?

Other than that, I do believe you're doing it the right why.

As you need values from all of the tables, you need to join them all, which is what you've done.

Comment: No, the `GROUP BY` clause is correct; he's using a MySQL string aggregate called `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate the tags into a comma-delimited list, though the SQL isn't legal as he's selecting non-grouped and non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: DESC because I want the latest one to be the first one

Answer (score 0):

The only other option you have is to use a multi-table select, e.g.

```
   SELECT thread.title, thread.id as thread_id,
   thread.content, author.username, author.id as author_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.name ORDER BY tag.name DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags
   FROM thread, thread_tags, tag, author_threads, author
   WHERE thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
       AND thread_tags.tag_id = tag.id
       AND thread.id = author_threads.thread_id
       AND author_threads.author_id = author.id
   GROUP BY thread.id DESC
   LIMIT 0, 30
```

Support for this may be database-dependent though.

Comment: ARGH!  *runs screaming for the hills*

Comment: Hmm, over-reaction maybe, but I'd personally recommend against using this (admittedly syntactically correct) style.  The style the OP used exists because its so much more maintainable :)

Comment: Fair enough - I'm rather used to this style as it seems to be the preferred syntax used at my current workplace.

Comment: Support for this is not RDBMS-dependent, but be aware that this is a deprecated style and shouldn't be used for new development. The `join` keyword was introduced in SQL/92 and is the preferred way of describing joins in a query.

Comment: Also note that the use of non-aggregated, non-grouped columns within the select clause (when either implicit or explicit grouping is in place, such as here) is illegal in all RDBMS's *except* MySQL, and is not ANSI-compliant SQL.

Comment: No, it's supported by Oracle as well, aggregated/grouped or not, and is the traditional Oracle join style. Still, I take the points about readability and RDBMS-portability.